# Not able to read messages while making tcp ip connection in delphi

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp, delphi-xe2, indy

I have on exe which is I run on my local machine (127.0.0.1). This exe writes at port 1234 and reads at 5678. exe writes after every 50 seconds an integer value say  1212, 4545. 6767 etc. I want to read that integer value and display. So I am using Indy Client to serve the purpose. I have developed following code snippet for that.

```
IdTCPClient1.Port  := 1234; //Set port to connect to
IdTCPClient1.Host := '127.0.0.1'; //Set host to connect to
IdTCPClient1.Connect; //Make connection

sMsg := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn; //Read the response from the server
ShowMessage(sMsg);
```

But its not reading. While debugging it gets stuck at line (sMsg := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn;)

When I try to do this by using telnet command like this
telnet 127.0.0.1 1234
some miscellaneous or special characters are displayed after regular intervals not the integer values which server sends.

Please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: First of all, the `ReadLn` function waits until it gets a newline before returning, if its a plain newline or a carriage-return and newline combination I do not know. Also, how do you send those numbers, as binary data or as text strings?

Comment: The server application sends only integer value after 50 seconds (telegram is sent on a 4 byte big block as an integer value). Thats all I know. What should I use instead of ReadLn?

Comment: I'm not at home with Delphi, but I would imagine that a function named `ReadLn` would expect textual data, and not binary data. There should be some function named `Read` or `Receive` or similar, that should be used for arbitrary data.

Comment: "strings are null-terminated" means string are c compatible not delphi compatible. So will ReadLn function will work here which searches for newline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about where resides your problem, so, I'm posting a full example to create a basic Indy Server and Client applications.

First, I have a server application with a [`IdTCPServer`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdTCPServer.html) component and a button.  Relevant properties are:

```
object Button1: TButton
  Text = 'Listen'
  OnClick = Button1Click
end
object IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer
  DefaultPort = 1234
  OnExecute = IdTCPServer1Execute
end
```

and the [`IdTCPServer.OnExecute`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdTCPServer_OnExecute.html) and `Button.OnClick` method on the server looks like this:

```
procedure TServerForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Active := not IdTCPServer1.Active;
  if IdTCPServer1.Active then
    Button1.Text := 'Close'
  else
    Button1.Text := 'Listen';
end;

procedure TServerForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Num: Integer;
begin
  while (IdTCPServer1.Active) and (AContext.Connection.Connected) do
  begin
    Num := Random(MaxInt);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(IntToStr(Num));
    Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, for each connected client, we will enter a loop where each second will be written a random number (as string) to the socket.

I execute the server and press the button to start listening, accept the Firewall warning to allow the port open and then I can successfully connect and get information from this server via telnet:

[image: telnet connected to my server]

Now, I created the client application.

A Button, Memo and IdTCPClient on the form, relevant properties are:

```
object Button1: TButton
  Text = 'Connect'
  OnClick = Button1Click
end
object Memo1: TMemo
end
object IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient
  Host = 'localhost'
  Port = 1234
end
```

and the code looks like this:

```
procedure TClientForm.ReadResults;
var
  S: string;
begin
  while IdTCPClient1.Connected do
  begin
    S := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    //don't repeat this approach in production code, it's just a test here
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;

procedure TClientForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IdTCPClient1.Connected then
  begin
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    Button1.Text := 'Connect';
  end
  else
  begin
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    Button1.Text := 'Disconnect';
    Button1.Repaint;
    ReadResults;
  end;
end;
```

At runtime it looks like this:

[image: client and server running]

The project is made in FireMonkey with Delphi XE3, but it should work also with VCL with any Delphi version that supports Indy 10.

Comment: Thanks jachguate for posting a detailed example. But my problem is that I don't know in which language the server code is written. I am given only the exe file and I only know that it returns some integer value after every 50 seconds and just I have to do is to develop an application in delphi xe2 to read those integers.

Comment: Do you have any spec document which describes in which format that number is _written_. If it is written in binary format, that's a whole different story and you _MUST_ know which data-type you can use to match what the server writes to implement it properly on the client side. Per your question, if you can't read it using telnet, or the server is not writing it properly or it is in binary format –you get some _rare_ prints in telnet, like echoing a binary file.

Comment: I think its in binary format. Please find the screenshot of my telnet getting response  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AeVywDHW5QvW8Hunu-mB4-3J4ohS5iB5PrWA_m_U6AM/edit    So, what should I do now. How can I read this?

Comment: It looks like you have to figure out what's what you're getting (really no spec at all?), I suggest you read all the available bytes and show it as a Hex dump to figure out what you have. After that try to map what you see to a structure that matches the size and shape of the bytes. That's (reverse engineering) is an art of guess, by trial and error.

Comment: One more hint I have, might be you get some clue or not :( "strings are null-terminated" means string are c compatible not delphi compatible. So will ReadLn function will work here which searches for newline?

Comment: You can read until any character you consider the _end of the string_ appears on the channel. IOHandler.ReadLn have overloaded versions in which you pass the _terminator_ string like this: IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn(#0);

But if you're getting binary information, you don't want to read it using ReadLn, but ReadBytes, ReadInt64, ReadLongInt, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19857/discussion-between-jachguate-and-naresh-kumar)